# Determining customer's country on what? IP Address?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

**Introduction**
I've a question about something that I think it can become a little tricky... or maybe not, anyway. Considering I have to implement a web application which allow users to buy things online, I must show listed price, and also make them pay this price, depending on the user's country.

**Question**
What is the best practice to get this informations?

**Possible scenarios**

1. Asking user to specify it (*But I can't base my prices on that!*)
2. Base my price on the IP Address (*Is it safe enought? And how?*)
3. Any other ideas?

Comment: IP address doesn't say much - your database might be wring, customer might be using a proxy/VPN or simply sit somewhere in a hotel for a couple of days. You can use it as a pre-selection. Amazon.com does base the price on where you are (shipping/billing address) and you will see the price changing (Kindle newspaper subscription US vs international).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Base it on the customer's billing address or shipping address.

It's one thing if they're just going to say "I'll select the country with the best rate." It's another thing if they actually make a bank account in that country just for a good deal for you. And if they DO have a bank account in the cheap country, then it seems they should be eligible to purchase it as if they were in that country.

You can use the IP to show them an "estimated" price.

Personally, what I would do is have a base price for everyone, and then appropriate taxes, tariffs, and shipping costs depending on the other information. If people are buying internationally they will be used to this.

Comment: Yea but what if I must show price even if user not yet logged. Should I base my price on a "default" price. Let's say US price?

Comment: You could use the IP to show an "estimated" price, or you could use the US price. An important question: Is the price always the same but in different currencies? Like, in the US it's 100$ but in the EU it's 75Euro? Or is it actually radically different depending on country.

Comment: Thanks glow, I will go with that, as I thought

Answer (score 2):

I would never use the IP Address. The user could be using a Proxy. [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/) is the bigest shop and is based on the Shiping address. I would do the same.

Comment: You could use it as a 'best guess' until the final total is calculated.

Comment: @glowcoder : Yea, for sure! Because it's maybe more for when user not authenticated yet. So when he logged, I could get the billing informations or shipping on like you said before

Answer (score 1):

i wouldnt claim to know the best practice for this, but i can tell you conclusively that steam (a game content delivery network) does this based purely on the IP address, if that has any usefulness to you.

Comment: Thank to you, but a game is not like playing with money! I must be absolutly sure about what I show to users.

Comment: they sell games there, it very much is dealing with money.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Imho, you should not worry about that.

Your products should have a base currency (like dolar) and from there, if a user wants to buy that product, the user should pay that product in the base currency (dolar). Right?

All the convertion should be made by his bank provider or anything he uses to buy that item.

Or you really really need that requirement?

Comment: It was to give a "I've told ya!" for an evaluation and that it's simply just not safe to base something on IPAddress as I thought.

Comment: Yup, never trust the IP you get. But my answer is like, "why do you need that?". If you check amazon, e.g., they don't have the price of product by user country. Product cost 31.3€, the user will pay 31.3€... doesn't matter where he is. Perhaps I misunderstood your question. Do you really need thar requirement? And why?

Comment: It's depending on the ERP we are using. It gets a price related to the location. I would usualy do it like you said and make the paying module converting it for me (paypal, beanstream, etc) but not this time!